# customizing listview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Using the preferenceActivity, I created a list with different form gadgets
for example: 3 rows with checkboxes
2 with seek-bars

How can we customize the list view items. In the same list view I want to create different items, some with checkboxes, others with toggle buttons and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To customize the listview in order to add buttons which are not part of the list elements but part of the listview screen as a whole you can for example, create a listview.xml file like this (I left out unimportant parts):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
(...)
  />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
(...)
  />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
(...)
  />

  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/listv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
(...)
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then create listview like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  setContentView(R.layout.listview);
```

If you want to customize individual elements do the following, create a file such as list_item.xml. This example adds an imageview on the left side and a textview to the right, the textview is used to display the text of the list item. Add buttons and what have you to taste:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
  />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/listlabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the ArrayAdapter class do something like this:

```
class CustArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
  CustArrayAdapter()
  {
    super(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.listlabel, ListActivity.arrayofdata);
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    int mag;
    char c;

    View row=convertView;
    if (row==null)
    {
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listlabel);
    ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.listicon);

    label.setText(ListActivity.arrayofdata[position]);
    label.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff1111"));
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

    label.setText(ListActivity.arrayofdata[position]);

    return (row);
  }
}
```

What the last code block also does by the way is it generates the listview items "on the fly" when they scroll into view. This is a major improvement as opposed to having all items already created in memory, the latter will cause you to run out of memory really fast! And memory is scarce on many Android devices.

Comment: thanks, i get it, but what modifications should i do to allow different types of rows to be in the list view, and thank you again

Comment: I haven't done this but I think in the CustArrayAdapter() class you may be able to select on something like "if arrayofdata[position].somevalue==anothervalue" then create this_list_item, else another_list_item.